# How do I fix a parameter in a partial derivative?

Tags: math-mode

I would like to fix a parameter in a partial derivative in order to have something like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFbfi.jpg
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That looks like `\(\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V\)`. What's the problem?

Comment: You're welcome. If that solved your problem, you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 3):

That picture looks like

```
\(\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V\).
```

Comment: Expect @egreg's wrath about `\left(` and `\right)` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Should I quickly change `\(` and `\)` to `$...$` to get some more comments about bad style?

Comment: Yes, or `$$...$$` :-P

Comment: And use `\over` to construct the fraction.

Answer (score 1):

The `esdiff` package makes it easy to type: the `\diffp*` command  accepts 3 arguments (function in numerator, variables in denominator, evaluation point). It can calculate by itself the order of derivation in crossed derivatives.

You have options to have the differential symbol upright (default) or italic, and to set horizontal spacings between the differential symbol and what follows, or between the differential symbols of variables for crossed derivatives.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\diffp*{U}{T}{V}\quad \diffp*{f(x,y )}{{x^2} y}{(x_0,y_0)} \\
 \diffp{f}{xy} = \diffp{f}{yx}
\end{gather*}%

\end{document}
```

[image]